# lambda authorizer is not invoked

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I have implemented a lambda authorizer and integrated it with a lambda proxy integration on the API Gateway.

When I test the authorizer from the API Gateway it works fine, however when I try to invoke the endpoints, on the second lambda, from Postman, the request seems to skip the authorizer and hits directly the second lambda.

[image]

I tried also to use the authorizer not only on the API level but also for every method in the API, but that didn't help either.
[image]

Comment: Because your authorization is cached? Checkout your screenshot, turn off authorization caching?

Comment: Have you definitely deployed the API after adding the authorizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Authorization is cached for 5 minutes, it does not invoke the authorizer every time you call your API.